# Java - JSON with undefined Keys

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I have to read a JSON without knowing the keys.

My JSON is like this:

```
{
 "hello": {
   "bye": {
    "a": "1",
     "b": "2",
     "c": "3"
   },
   "d": "4",
   "e": "5"
 },
 "hey": {
  "qwer": {
     "asdf": "1",
     "fda": "2",
     "bc": "3"
   },
   "dq": "4"
 }
}
```

just with more data and more elements.

I would like to access them like a map using a path, just with e.g.

```
get() for hello&hey, 

get("hello") for bye,d&e, 

get("hello","bye") for a,b&c

...
```

I hope you understood me, I usually use Gson to parse JSON but passing a corresponding class (like `AClass c = new Gson.fromJson(myJson, AClass.class);`), but without knowing the JSON structure, I cannot use this approach.

It would be also great if I could easily remove and add entries somewhere.

Comment: I think you forgot to post your programming problem.

Comment: It's a Map.  You can iterate through the keys of a Map.

Comment: ... So what's the question?

Comment: i want to access them like a map, but i dont know how, i have just a huge json (2mb), i could'nt find anything for gson to access the data

Comment: You don't know how to use a regular JSON parser???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you need, you can still use Gson, but you need a more "low level" class like the `JsonParser`.

Here I provide you an example on how you can navigate the `JsonElement` tree generated by the parser to reach the requested node. It works only on syntaxes like you requested (node1/node2/..) but you can easily adapt also to cases like this: node1/3/node3/4/2 where the number indicates the child.

When you reach the node, you can parse using a Gson if you need, since you can pass to `Gson::fromJson` a `JsonElement` also. Here's the code:

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class Q20883087 {

  public static JsonElement get(JsonElement je, String...  args){
     if(args.length == 0)
        return je;

     if (je != null && je.isJsonObject()){
        String[] newArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);
       return get(je.getAsJsonObject().get(args[0]), newArgs); 
     }


   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String json ="{                          "+
      "   \"hello\": {            "+
      "     \"bye\": {            "+
      "      \"a\": \"1\",        "+
      "       \"b\": \"2\",       "+
      "       \"c\": \"3\"        "+
      "     },                    "+
      "     \"d\": \"4\",         "+
      "     \"e\": \"5\"          "+
      "   },                      "+
      "   \"hey\": {              "+
      "    \"qwer\": {            "+
      "       \"asdf\": \"1\",    "+
      "       \"fda\": \"2\",     "+
      "       \"bc\": \"3\"       "+
      "     },                    "+
      "     \"dq\": \"4\"         "+
      "   }                       "+
      "  }                        ";

      JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(json);

      System.out.println(get(jsonElement, "hello","bye"));
      System.out.println(get(jsonElement, "hey","qwer"));




   }

}
```

The result is:

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
{"asdf":"1","fda":"2","bc":"3"}
```

Pay attention to the recursive nature of the get method, since Json is recursive by nature, the best way to manage it is using a recursive method.